# Why does jQuery add a class to an image whenI click it even though I haven't specifically asked it to?

Tags: jquery, class, click

Found this recently, but can't for the life of me figure out how the "clickedClass" bit manages to add the "selected" class to the thumbnail...

Change "selected" to anything you like and it still works.

```
        var activeOpacity   = 1.0,
            inactiveOpacity = 0.6,
            fadeTime = 200,
            clickedClass = "selected",
            thumb = "#thumbnailContainer div img";
        $(thumb).fadeTo(1, inactiveOpacity);

        $(thumb).hover(
            function(){
                $(this).stop().fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
            },
            function(){
                if(!$(this).hasClass(clickedClass)) {
                    $(this).stop().fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);
                }

        $(thumb).click(function() {
             var clicked, previous;
             clicked = $(this);
             if (!clicked.hasClass(clickedClass)) {
                 previous = $(thumb+'.'+clickedClass);
                 previous.removeClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, inactiveOpacity);
                 clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
             }
         });

                });
```

Yes, I know - "it works", but WHY does it work?

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated,

JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line adds the "selected" class to the thumb.

```
clicked.addClass(clickedClass).fadeTo(fadeTime, activeOpacity);
```

here clicked = to the thumbnail and clickedClass = "Selected"

Comment: !!! Sorry, I'm idiot. Read through code VERY slowly and figured the thing out. Shame is me. Easter stuff, JS.

Comment: ...thanks for getting back to me so quickly btw, happy trails, JS

Answer (score 0):

because `thumb = "#thumbnailContainer div img"`

and `$("#thumbnailContainer div img")` is a jQuery selector

and this line: `$(this).hasClass(clickedClass)` checks if the thumbnail has the clickedClass in your case `"selected"` or any other class.